# Texstudio compile not compile current document

Tags: texstudio

I worked and compiled a document and create a new one. I attempt "Build & View" newly created document but TeXstudio compiles only old one.

Comment: please add the code to make us  understand what you say

Comment: Mostly your document is not getting compiled. Remove pdf file manually and again compile and see if you get errors

Comment: You can add a master file to your project. file -> close all should do the trick

Comment: Sounds like something that could happen if the old document was still open, and defined as a Master document. Is the old one still open? To set the new one as master, do *Options --> Define Current document as Master document.*

Comment: @SteveSamuels: Sorry, I cannot figure out how to do it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

TeXstudio allows you to define a given file as a *master document*. The purpose of this is to ease compiling when working with multiple files. For example when writing a document where each chapter is in a separate file, one still has to compile the main file where the preamble is found, not the chapter file (starting with `\chapter`). My defining the main file as a master document under *Options --> Root document* (in older versions of TeXstudio this is *Options --> Define Current Document as Master Document*), one doesn't have to switch to this before compiling.

Hence, if you still have your old file open and this is selected as master document, when you try to compile the new file, the old one will be compiled. To fix this, set the new file as master document instead.

Comment: Yes, now I understand the need for such organization. Actually I really needed a option "Online Preview".

Comment: In new versions (such as TeXstudio 2.12.0), this options has been renamed to **Root Document** and it's available under **Options** menu.